# Separate first name with middle name and last name with strtok_r

Tags: c, strtok, etcpasswd

So im having some issues related to my previous quest in C programming. This time on how to separate names from `/etc/passwd` file using `strtok_r` or `strtok`. The deal is that I want to separate the users names in two parts, first name and middle name (assuming they got one) in the first, and the last name in the second. But I can't find a way to separate the names correctly. I got it to work with their first name in the first part, but then the middle name is attached to the last name.

The `/etc/passwd` lines looks like this:

```
s214907:x:1240:1251:Jonas Villa,,,:/home/s214907:/bin/bash
s212167:x:1297:1306:Konstantina Pavlova Rusenkova,,,:/home/s212167:/bin/bash
```

Example of what I get:

```
[Konstantina] [Pavlova Ruskenova]
```

Example of how I want it to print:

```
[Konstantina Pavlova] [Ruskenova]
```

This is my code so far:

```
          char line[256], words[20];
          char *mname, *tmp, *uid, *sp, *lname, *uname, *name, *fname, *tmps;
          int bindex=0, index, cnt =0, count;
          char *rest = NULL;
          FILE*fp = fopen("/etc/passwd","r");
          size_t len = 0;
          char *next = NULL;
          while(fgets(line,256,fp)!=NULL)
          {
                  sp       = strtok(line, ":");
                  tmp      = strtok(NULL, ":");
                  uid      = strtok(NULL, ":");
                  tmp      = strtok(NULL, ":");
                  name     = strtok(NULL, ":,");




                  if(atoi(uid) > 999)
                  {
                          for(tmps = strtok_r(name, " ", &rest);
                                  tmps != NULL;
                                  tmps = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &rest)) {
                                  tmps = strtok(tmps, ",");
                                  printf("[%s]\n", tmps);
                          }
                  }
                  cnt++;
          }
          fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Please show how you define and initialize all your variables (including input to handle). Please do not add line numbers in front of the line as it is hard to read.

Comment: If you get wrong output, please show us what you get wrong. Apart from splitting some string you do not do anything with those strings. Where do you combine them into the brackets?

Comment: @Gerhardh my output is: [Andrea] [Brask Sittlinger]

But I need it to be [Andrea Brask] [Sittlinger]

Comment: Please add this to the qeustion. Together with the given input.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by that @Gerhardh, I did mention what im struggling with in the description?

Comment: OK, I misread the question a bit. Wrong output is there. But the provided input is missing. I don't have a passwd at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach to use `strtok_r` or `strtok` to split the names cannot work.

After you tokenize the (complete) name, you get this:

```
name="Konstantina Pavlova Rusenkova"
```

You get this name by `name = strtok(NULL, ":,");`. Therefore it cannot contain any `','`. If there was a `','` the string would have been chopped there.

Any further tokenization using delimiter `','` cannot get any useful result except to return the complete string itself.

This means in your inner loop `tmps = strtok(tmps, ",");` will not do anything.

I added a few prints:

```
printf("name=%s\n",name);

    if(atoi(uid) > 999)
    {
        for(tmps = strtok_r(name, " ", &rest);
            tmps != NULL;
            tmps = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &rest))
        {
            printf("tmps:%s\n", tmps); 
            tmps = strtok(tmps, ",");
            printf("  [%s]\n", tmps);
        }
    }
```

The result is:

```
name=Konstantina Pavlova Rusenkova
tmps:Konstantina
  [Konstantina]
tmps:Pavlova Rusenkova
  [Pavlova Rusenkova]
```

The second print shows what you feed into your `tmps=strtok(tmps,",");`. As mentioned above the delimiter is never present leaving everything in the second brackets.

In general, `strtok` and friends is not useful for splitting the name. If cuts the strings apart leaving no two names together. The whitespace is replaced by `\0`.

Instead you could simply search for the last whitespace and split there:

```
    if(atoi(uid) > 999)
    {
        char *first = name;
        char *last = strrchr(name,' ');

        if (last != NULL)
        {
            *last = 0;
            last++;

            printf("[%s] [%s]\n", first, last);
        }
    }
```

This will get

```
name=Konstantina Pavlova Rusenkova
[Konstantina Pavlova] [Rusenkova]
```

It also still works for names with only 1 first name:

```
name=James Kirk
[James] [Kirk]
```

If there is only one name in total you need to adapt a bit.

Note:

If for some reason you insist to use `strtok` also for splitting the name, you need to use delimiter `' '` and then glue together the first and second substring.

This would look like this:

```
    if(atoi(uid) > 999)
    {
        for(tmps = strtok_r(name, " ", &rest);
            tmps != NULL;
            tmps = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &rest))
            {
                printf("tmps:%s\n", tmps);
                printf("  [%s]\n", tmps);
        }
    }
```

with output

```
name=Konstantina Pavlova Rusenkova
tmps:Konstantina
  [Konstantina]
tmps:Pavlova
  [Pavlova]
tmps:Rusenkova
  [Rusenkova]
```

Comment: Whoa, thanks. Really appreciate the explanation and the time you took!
Helped me a lot to understand how this works :)